# Git: could not read from remote repository

Tags: windows, git, ssh-keygen

My work group is trying to move it's code base from the good ole shared file system method to a private git server.  We've followed [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) up to chapter 4.4 where any semblance of hinting at how to do this on a Windows based server evaporates.  <s>At first, we ignored this section except as reference, strictly because we already use PuTTY and WinSCP to access the remote server, and believed our already-shared and existing SSH keys from those sessions would be there waiting for us.  Instead,</s> we get the following error:

```
fatal: '/C/GitRepository/NAV.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The folder is there and is accessible on the remote server.

We are aware this question is asked about a dozen times here on SO, but the fix still eludes us.  <s>Can anyone provide some Windows specific assistance in how to go about setting up the keys (or, if those keys from PuTTY and WinSCP sessions are usable, what else could be the problem)?</s>

[image]

[image]

Comment: `/C/` seems like a *local* file path. Is this a network drive? (I don't really "do" Windows but it's clear that network drives won't be going over ssh in the first place.)

Comment: C is the root drive of any windows machine.

Comment: Right, so, GIt is complaining that a repository on the local drive is not a Git repository. Ssh has not come into the picture yet, and any ssh issues should be irrelevant. The `remote.origin.url` does matter at this point, certainly. But `/C/GitRepository/NAV.git` also sure *does* look like a repository, so the complaint itself is puzzling.

Comment: Here is the output from `git remote get-url origin`

    EO3742@MyLocal MINGW64 ~/Development/Java/NAV (master)
    $ git remote get-url origin
    ssh://eo3742@RemoteMachine:22/C:\GitRepository\NAV.git

Comment: It appears your Windows-ized Git is not treating that as an ssh directive, and instead trying to read from `C:\...` directly. It may be worth trying some alternative pathname, such as `ssh://eo3742@RemoteMachine/C/GitRepository/NAV.Git`. In any case it seems whoever ported your particular Git to Windows seems to have broken it, as `ssh://` should pass the rest of the URL to ssh itself, uninterpreted, and then ssh should pass the non-host part to the server, uninterpreted.

Comment: The guy who installed it isn't in the office for a few days so I can't ask directly, but as far as I can tell, this is plain vanilla Git downloaded from git-scm.com - no TortoiseGit, Atlassian or any of the other flavors. When I run Git Bash on the remote server and cd into NAV.git, the path displayed by bash is `/c/GitRepository/NAV.git` but that doesn't seem to work either.  When I `git init --bare` on the remote server in that directory, Git says `C:/GitRepository/NAV.git/`.  Frustrating

Comment: That might be the problem itself, I get the impression that people use msysgit or TortoiseGit or whatever because vanilla Git doesn't play well with Windows. But, again, I don't actually *use* Windows (in the past I've used cygwin when necessary, but that was over ten years ago).

Comment: I appreciate your help.  If you change your last to be an answer, I'll accept that, since it appears the only way out of this.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in the path portion need to be forward slash, not the windows backslash separator.  Include the semi-colon.

```
/C:/GitRepository/NAV
```